# Div toggle, option select inside it

Tags: html, css

I have a div which toggles when clicked on it.

Now my problem is when I put an option select box inside the div, whenever I want to select something the div toggles and therefor closes.

Anyway to solve this ?

HTML :

```
 <div class="click>
 <div class="red">
 <select>
 <option>
 OPTION1
 </option>
 <option>
 OPTION2
 </option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$(".click").click(function(){
   $(this).children("div").toggle();
});
```

Comment: We would like to see some code.

Comment: any code indeed? It seems like your click on the selectbox triggers the toggle of the div.

Comment: From the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Be specific. We also would need code.

Comment: Hi Frank, yes indeed that is what happens. Anyway to prevent it ?

Comment: @Frank Noordeloos See, I was thinking that too, and I even went to put a decent solution to that problem. But I can't confirm anything without OPs code. It's like getting a problem that says "Solve for x", but without any grounds for variables.

Comment: From myself : Read the code carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add a click handler on the select element

```
$(".click").click(function(){
   $(this).children("div").toggle();
});
$(".click select").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2MkHc/

Answer (score 1):

How about this logic.

1) Get the element being clicked using [**`event.target`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

2) Using **`.prop("tagname")`** get the tagname being clicked.

```
$(".click").click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).prop("tagName") != "SELECT") {
        $(this).children("div").toggle();
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnySu/1/)

Hope you like this methodology.